# Error while writing an asynchronous function for deletion on FASTAPI

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

The function should delete an item (Bookings) taking room_id and user_id.In the terminal it says `"DELETE /bookings/10 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK,` but nothing is deleted from the database.
I am new in this business

```
 @classmethod
    async def remove(cls, user_id: int, room_id: int):
            async with async_session_maker() as session:
                query = select(Rooms).filter_by(id=room_id)
                result = await session.execute(query)
                result = result.scalar_one_or_none()
                if result is None:
                    raise {"message": "Room not found"}

                delete_query = delete(Bookings).filter_by(room_id=room_id, user_id=user_id)
                print(delete_query)
                await session.execute(delete_query)
```

```
@router.delete("/{id}")
async def remove_booking(
        id: int,
        user: Users = Depends(get_current_user),
):
    await BookingDAO.remove(user.id, id)
```

Honestly, I can't think of anything that could be wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing a commit after you execute the delete.

Try this:

```py
await session.execute(delete_query)
await session.commit()
```